php long datatable url return 403 forbidden
i am facing issue with long query string of datatable almost 800 params i guess
https://insurancedata.com/insurer/products/listing?draw=1&columns%5B0%5D%5Bdata%5D=checkbox&columns%5B0%5D%5Bname%5D=checkbox&columns%5B0%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=false&columns%5B0%5D%5Borderable%5D=false&columns%5B0%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B0%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B1%5D%5Bdata%5D=product_name&columns%5B1%5D%5Bname%5D=product_name&columns%5B1%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B1%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B1%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B1%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B2%5D%5Bdata%5D=product_code&columns%5B2%5D%5Bname%5D=product_code&columns%5B2%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B2%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B2%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B2%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B3%5D%5Bdata%5D=product_plan&columns%5B3%5D%5Bname%5D=product_plan&columns%5B3%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B3%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B3%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B3%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B4%5D%5Bdata%5D=rating_template&columns%5B4%5D%5Bname%5D=rating_template&columns%5B4%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B4%5D%5Borderable%5D=false&columns%5B4%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B4%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B5%5D%5Bdata%5D=company_name&columns%5B5%5D%5Bname%5D=company_name&columns%5B5%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B5%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B5%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B5%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B6%5D%5Bdata%5D=subclass&columns%5B6%5D%5Bname%5D=subclass&columns%5B6%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B6%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B6%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B6%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B7%5D%5Bdata%5D=added_by&columns%5B7%5D%5Bname%5D=added_by&columns%5B7%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B7%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B7%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B7%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B8%5D%5Bdata%5D=status&columns%5B8%5D%5Bname%5D=status&columns%5B8%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B8%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B8%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B8%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B9%5D%5Bdata%5D=created_at&columns%5B9%5D%5Bname%5D=created_at&columns%5B9%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B9%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B9%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B9%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B10%5D%5Bdata%5D=updated_at&columns%5B10%5D%5Bname%5D=updated_at&columns%5B10%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B10%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B10%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B10%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B11%5D%5Bdata%5D=updated_by&columns%5B11%5D%5Bname%5D=updated_by&columns%5B11%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B11%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B11%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B11%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B12%5D%5Bdata%5D=action&columns%5B12%5D%5Bname%5D=action&columns%5B12%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B12%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B12%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B12%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&order%5B0%5D%5Bcolumn%5D=8&order%5B0%5D%5Bdir%5D=asc&start=0&length=10&search%5Bvalue%5D=&search%5Bregex%5D=false&class_id=2&_token=2Y3nvFtVS8btTtr8oLeGgJDi4dJ1Eq397XGi6CFy&_=1722267836255

i am using ubuntu. above url says 403 Forbidden
but if i decrease the params it works fine
my php settings are
upload_max_filesize = 200M
max_file_uploads = 200
max_execution_time = 240
max_input_time = 120
max_input_vars = 6000
memory_limit = 1G
post_max_size = 200M

any help?

"almost 800 params" - that looks way too long for a GET request. Why not use a POST request?

403 Forbidden error suggests that the server is rejecting the request due to its length. But in PHP, there isn't a specific limit on the length of the query string itself. Instead, the limitation is typically imposed by the web server and the browser.
I am not sure whether you have Apache or Nginx. So, let me update you for both.
If you Using Apache:
Apache has a directive called LimitRequestLine that sets the limit on the size of the HTTP request line. The default limit is 8190 bytes (approximately 8190 characters). To change this limit, you can add or modify the LimitRequestLine directive in your Apache configuration file:
LimitRequestLine 16384

Restart Apache Server
sudo systemctl restart apache2


If you Using Nginx:
Open your Nginx configuration file, typically located at:
 /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

Add or update the large_client_header_buffers directive to allocate larger buffers for your headers:
http {
    large_client_header_buffers 4 16k;
    ...
}

Restart Nginx
sudo systemctl restart nginx


After that you should be able to handle longer query strings without encountering the 403 Forbidden error.

let me give a try

aws firewall was causing the issue and we have removed all rules and it is working fine now.
